# How to store value into a generated barcode using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inventory-management

Recently im developing a inventory management system ,web application using ASP.NET MVC.

I would like to store value into a barcode (code39).

If I scan the generated barcode with live camera, it will shows the detail of product, eg. product name, description...

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use a [library](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/barcode) for this.

Comment: Show your progress, code, and what you've tried